# Can we say brute-force is completely exploration-based?

Tags: algorithms

My definition of exploration is

> [Exploration] refers to searching a much larger portion of the search
> space with the hope of finding other promising solutions that are yet
> to be refined. This amounts to diversifying the search in order to
> avoid getting trapped in a local minimum.

While hill-climbing is completely exploitation-based, and simulated annealing is a mix of both, can we say brute-force is therefore the completely exploration-based approach, or does the exploitation-exploration concept only work with these 'heuristics' that don't give an absolute result?

Comment: Could you please give a context of the task? I think the answer would vary depending on whether it's just a thought or a statement in the paper.

Comment: @DmitriiBadretdinov oh sorry, it's more of just a thought. I was writing notes for a class and was giving examples for approaches to the travelling salesman that were more exploitation-based and which were more exploration-based, and was just wondering if brute-force would be one. I'm really new to these concepts, so sorry if what I asked makes no sense.

Comment: Don't worry, the question is fine in terms of making sense.